# Hidden Field Flow Using Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, hidden-field

I'm trying to receive a `POST` then generate a form with new fields and pass along the values I received in the previous `POST` as hidden variables.  I've done a lot of searching in documentation and can't seem to find anything that connects the two sides of this flow.  I'm using Django 1.4 w/ Python 2.7.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from gateway_interface.forms import newForm

def requestNewForm(request):
    if (request.method == "POST"):
        form = newForm(request)

        return render_to_response('myTemplate.html', {'form' : form})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
class newForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, request):
        my_passed_variable = request.POST['pass_variable']

    a_new_variable = forms.CharField(max_length = 25)

    my_passed_variable = forms.CharField(widget = forms.HiddenInput())
```

myTemplate.html

```
<form action="/myNextDjangoView/" method="post">
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        I need this value: {{ form.a_new_variable }} <br>
    </div>

    {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
        {{ hidden }}
    {% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I must be doing something fundamentally wrong.  If I use the for loop in the template none of the visible fields show on the page.  Nothing I've tried has caused the hidden fields to populate.

Any suggestions?  Perhaps I'm missing an import somewhere?  Is there something I need to import in `forms.py` to allow for the use of `HiddenInput()`?

EDIT 1:
I've modified `forms.py` to look like this:

```
form django import forms
class newForm(forms.Form):
    a_new_variable = forms.CharField(max_length = 25)
    my_passed_variable = forms.CharField(widget = forms.HiddenInput())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(newForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

This has not changed my output.  I still get the same form with no fields showing (hidden or visible).  What I need to do is instantiate with an initialization dictionary.  (I think?) Where the dictionary contains the name and values for all the hidden fields.

```
initial_dict = { 'my_passed_variable' : request.POST.get('pass_variable') }
form = newForm(initial = initial_dict)
```

EDIT 2:

Using the initialization dictionary was a step in the right direction!  I am now able to see the visible fields in my form but the hidden fields are still not populating.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from gateway_interface.forms import newForm

def requestNewForm(request):
    if (request.method == "POST"):
        initial_dict = { 'my_passed_variable' : request.POST.get('pass_variable') }
        form = newForm(initial = initial_dict)

        return render_to_response('myTemplate.html', {'form' : form})
```

EDIT 3:

I've got it working.  Thanks to Jordan Reiter for pushing me in the right direction.  It turns out the problem was almost entirely the caching of my browser after `EDIT 1` above.  I moved to Chrome's incognito mode and everything just worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a definite problem with this code:

```
from django import forms
class newForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, request):
        my_passed_variable = request.POST['pass_variable']

    a_new_variable = forms.CharField(max_length = 25)

    my_passed_variable = forms.CharField(widget = forms.HiddenInput())
```

First, it's incredibly confusing for there to be two variables with identical names (although one of them is `self.my_passed_variable` available throughout the form and the other is just `my_passed_variable` available in `__init__` only). I can't help but think you're trying to tie the two variables together somehow, but you're not. Worst/best case scenario (if you rewrote `my_passed_variable = request.POST['pass_variable']` as `self.my_passed_variable = request.POST['pass_variable']`) you're overwriting the value for form field object with a string.

Second, I'm assuming you snipped out a bunch of code from the `__init__` function. You're missing the `super` which actually makes this a form. As it stands, the form object is not going to be instantiated correctly.

If you're trying to do what I *think* you're trying to do, you want to rewrite it this way:

```
from django import forms
class newForm(forms.Form):
    # first, I'm going to put the fields at the top, I think that's more standard
    a_new_variable = forms.CharField(max_length = 25)
    my_passed_variable = forms.CharField(widget = forms.HiddenInput())

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(newForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['my_passed_variable'].initial = request.POST.get('pass_variable') # don't assume the variable is present!
```

Comment: I'm trying to make sense of what you have posted here but it's not working.  Is there proper documentation on how to do this?  I've scoured Django's site trying to find information on how to do this.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you are trying to change the value in the field, then this code is correct. How is it not working? What error message are you getting?